# How to know what is being downloaded?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, monitoring

I have Bitmeter 2 installed to monitor my download/upload state and now it indicates that my pc is downloading something but I have no idea what is being downloaded. Moreover, my partition C is running out of space so I guess there must be something is being stored on that.
How do I know which application/service is pulling stuff from the internet and where it stores on my hard disk ?

p/s: I'm using Windows 7 system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely just an update from one of your applications, you do not need to access these files.

Of course you could always go to Task Manager and peer at the "Network" usage column, generally clicking the "Network" tab to arrange Highest Network usage processes to Lowest, to determine what is accessing the network.

Comment: how to find out where the app stores the download into ?

Comment: Not sure, but definitely use Resource Monitor instead of what I described above to monitor network behavior. It's much more detailed. To access, open a Run prompt (win-key + r) and type resmon and hit enter.

Comment: exactly what you said, Resource Monitor shows everything. Thank you !